# Is it possible to embed a video to Windows Media Player?

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, c#-4.0, panel, axwindowsmediaplayer

I have a winform app in visual studio. On the main interface I have panels ( home panel, about us panel & contact us panel ). When I click the button that takes me to the home panel, I want the video to be there already( in Windows media player obviously ). And to be played automatically when the “ home panel button “ is clicked. The client shouldn’t have to go and look for the video.

Is there a way to do this? 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

- Add WMP control to the "Toolbox" panel in Visual Studio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmp/using-the-windows-media-player-control-with-microsoft-visual-studio
- Drag WMP control from Toolbox to your Home panel in the form designer.
- Add the video to the project and in it's properties, choose "Copy if newer" in "Copy to Output Directory" option.
- Override Form.OnLoad or find another suitable place and add code that gives the player the URL of the video and sets other properties.

  ```
  protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
  {
      base.OnLoad(e);

      var location = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
      var folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(location);
      var path = Path.Combine(folder, "small.avi");
      axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = path;

      axWindowsMediaPlayer1.uiMode = "none";

      // autoplay if current page index is 0 (home?)
      if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 0)
          axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
  }
  ```

If you want the player to restart playback everytime the page gets displayed, add handler to TabControl.SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
this.tabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

and implement it like this:

```
private void TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
}
```